# EF Core create a new database with username password

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible when running

```
dotnet ef database update
```

To create the database (if it does not exist) with a new username and password?

for example in my appsettings.json  when I have

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;user=user;password=password"
  },
```

I would like it to create a new database and create a  new user with the password specified.

but when I run  `dotnet ef database update`  I receive

> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean
>   errorsExpected)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean
>   errorsExpected)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime
>   giveUp)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext
>   c, TState s)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy
>   strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy
>   strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean
>   retryOnNotExists)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) ClientConnectionId:fc9fb778-b6e7-4276-a454-f627ca974133 Error
>   Number:18456,State:1,Class:14 Login failed for user 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute

```
dotnet ef database update
```

You are telling EF to execute the migrations and update the database, but you cannot connect to the database as the user and password you are using doesn't exists.
So you can create a database with ef (when you execute the first migration if the database doesn't exists, ef will create it), but you cannot create a new user and password through the connectionstring.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database